# Unable to delete file remotely

Tags: centos

```
[centos@JEN1 postAuthernticationPlugIn]$ id
uid=1000(centos) gid=1000(centos) groups=1000(centos),4(adm),10(wheel),190(systemd-journal)
```

I am running below command to delete file `PostAuthProcessing.class`:

```
ssh -i /var/test.pem centos@192.168.13.12 -tt sudo "rm /opt/tomcat/webapps/openam/WEB-INF/classes/PostAuthProcessing.class"
```

But the file do not get deleted and the commands hangs and does not return any error.

Please can anybody help?

Comment: Are you able to delete it locally? Check file permissions as well as the output of ssh in verbose mode (`ssh -v ......`)

Comment: does sudo work on target server for this user? What is the result of sudo "ls -laF /opt/tomcat/webapps/openam/WEB-INF/classes/PostAuthProcessing.class"